# affine curve. analysis

Tags: complex-analysis, riemann-surfaces

Can anyone explain what is written in book?
 $\Gamma(w,E)\equiv w^{2}-E^{n}+\sum_{i>0,j\ge 0, ni+2j<2n} g_{ij}w^{i}E^{j}=0, $
where $g_{1,0}$ doesn't equal to zero.

"At infinity it compactified by one point $p1$. (what does it mean? what is "infinity"? what the point?$((w,E), (E),(w)$).

"$w=w(p)$ has pole of order $n$ and E=E(p) has pole of order 2 at this point"

"And the curve has second marked point at which w has zero of order n"

Comment: Might want to give out the name of your book...

Comment: it's not a book. It's an article http://arxiv.org/abs/1403.4629